# How to split json data in columns to multi columns like this

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to convert data from input to output. in best way

**Input:**

```
  ColA  |  ColB
------------------
[3,6,3] | [6,5,8]
------------------
[1,2,3] | [9,9,8]
```

**Output:**

```
 ColA(1) | ColA(2) | ColA(3) | ColB(1) | ColB(2) | ColB(3) 
-----------------------------------------------------------
    3    |    6    |    3    |    6    |    5    |    8    
-----------------------------------------------------------
    1    |    2    |    3    |    9    |    9    |    8
```

Currently i use this code:

```
for h in ['ColA', 'ColB']:
    for i, item in enumerate(json.loads(df.iloc[0][h])):
        df[h + '(' + str(i+1) + ')'] = df[h].apply(lambda x: json.loads(x)[i])
        df = df.drop([h], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the beginning, you should covert your data to JSON.

```
In [13]: df.to_json()                                                                         
Out[13]: '{"colA":{"0":[3,6,3],"1":[1,2,3]},"colB":{"0":[6,5,8],"1":[9,9,8]}}'
```

As you can see, you have a json strings, so we need to load it.

```
In [14]: import json                                                                          

In [15]: js=json.loads(df.to_json())
```

And then, to flat your data:

```
In [23]: for k, v in js.items(): 
    ...:     for r, i in v.items(): 
    ...:         for c in range(len(i)): 
    ...:             new_column = "{}({})".format(k, c + 1)
```

For now, you have your new column name, such as (colA(1), colA(2)...)

To save your new data, you can use default dictionary data type:

```
In [20]: from collections import defaultdict                                                  

In [21]: flate = defaultdict(list)
```

And finally, you can store it.

```
In [23]: for k, v in js.items(): 
    ...:     for r, i in v.items(): 
    ...:         for c in range(len(i)): 
    ...:             new_column = "{}({})".format(k, c + 1) 
    ...:             print(new_column) 
    ...:             flate[new_column].append(i[c])
```

Covert it back to pandas data frame:

```
In [25]: df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=flate)                                                       

In [26]: df2                                                                                  
Out[26]: 
   colA(1)  colA(2)  colA(3)  colB(1)  colB(2)  colB(3)
0        3        6        3        6        5        8
1        1        2        3        9        9        8
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `pandas.concat` with `pandas.DataFrame`:

```
import pandas as pd

dfs = []
for c in df:
    tmp = pd.DataFrame(list(df[c]))
    tmp.columns = [c + '(%s)' % str(i+1) for i in range(tmp.shape[1])]
    dfs.append(tmp)

new_df = pd.concat(dfs, 1)
print(new_df)
```

Output:

```
   ColA(1)  ColA(2)  ColA(3)  ColB(1)  ColB(2)  ColB(3)
0        3        6        3        6        5        8
1        1        2        3        9        9        8
```